# (AttributeError: __enter__) when using __new__ magic method

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm trying to use `__new__` method to check for argument validity (str) before processing it, so i am doing as following:

```
class foo:

    def __new__(cls, argument):
        if not isinstance(argument, str):
            raise TypeError('argument must be str')
        print("passed __new__")

    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument
        print("passed __init__")

    def __enter__(self):
        print("passed __enter__")

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("passed __exit__")
```

#### then, when I call this using `with` keyword which calls `__enter__` and `__exit__`

```
with foo('test'):
    print("i am between __enter__ and __exit__, damn!")
```

#### I am getting this output:

```
passed __new__
AttributeError: __enter__
```

#### I expected this output:

```
passed __new__
passed __init__
passed __enter__
i am between __enter__ and __exit__, damn!
passed __exit__
```

I noticed when dropping `__new__` method entirely; it will work. Why does using `__new__` break that? and how can I get it to work even with `__new__` existing?

Comment: You are not creating the object properly. __new__ needs to call super().__new__(cls,argument) and then return the instance super().__new__() returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__new__` has to actually create and return an instance of your class.

```
class foo:

    def __new__(cls, argument):
        if not isinstance(argument, str):
            raise TypeError('argument must be str')
        print("passed __new__")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument
        print("passed __init__")

    def __enter__(self):
        print("passed __enter__")

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("passed __exit__")
```

In your original code, `foo.__new__` returned `None`, and indeed `None` has no attribute `__enter__`. Also, since `None` is not an instance of `foo`, the implicit call to `foo.__init__` was suppressed.

---

Since `foo` is an instance of `type`, the call `foo('test')` is short for

```
type.__call__(foo, 'test')
```

You can imagine `__call__` is defined something like

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

Overriding `__new__` means you want to change how the instance gets *created*, while overriding `__init__` means you want to change how an already-created instance gets *initialized*. In this case, you avoid creating a new instance altogether if the argument is of the wrong type.

Comment: why doesn't `return super().__new__(cls)` raise a missing argument exception since `argument` is absent?

Comment: Because `super().__new__` isn't calling `foo.__new__`; it's calling (in this case) `object.__new__`, which doesn't expect any other arguments aside from a class.